# Total Variation Distance

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Grimmett and Stirzaker in *Probability and Random Processes*, 3rd ed. have on pg. 44:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be integer-valued random variables, and let

$$d_{TV}(X,Y) = \sum_{k}{\vert P(X=k) - P(Y=k)\vert }.$$

They ask the reader to prove that $d_{TV}(X,Y) = 0$ iff $P(X=Y) = 1$. I have no problem with $P(X=Y) = 1 \implies d_{TV}(X,Y) = 0$ but the other direction, $d_{TV}(X,Y) = 0 \implies P(X=Y) = 1$, doesn't look valid to me.

Simple counter-example: One toss of a fair coin. Let $X$ be $1$ for $H$ and $0$ for $T$. Let $Y$ be $0$ for $H$ and $1$ for $T$. Then $d_{TV}(X,Y)=0$ but $P(X=Y)=0$ by my calculation.

It seems to me that $d_{TV}(X,Y)$ is more a measure of the "distance" between the distribution functions of $X$ and $Y$ rather than between $X$ and $Y$ themselves. In the example, $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution function.

I might well be missing something here and the book is correct, but is $d_{TV}(X,Y) = 0 \implies P(X=Y) = 1$ true? If so, could you provide a proof to confirm it?

Thanks.

Comment: The correct implication is that if $d_{TV}(X,Y)=0$ then there exists some probability space $\Omega'$ and some random variables $X'$ and $Y'$ defined on $\Omega'$ such that $X=X'$ in distribution, $Y=Y'$ in distribution, and $P(X'=Y')=1$.

Comment: And the complete exercise in G&S where this appears should be rewritten, apparently.

Comment: @Did Thanks very much for your reply. $d_{TV}(X,Y)=0$ seems to imply $X,Y$ must have the same distribution (in this integer-valued case). In which case, your $\Omega^{'}, X^{'}, Y^{'}$ could be satified respectively by $\Omega, X, X$. Would you agree?

Comment: Yes, when $d_{TV}(X,Y)=0$, this is true. I found useful to recall the general caracterization of $d_{TV}(X,Y)$ as the infimum of $P'(X'\ne Y')$ over $P'$, $X'$ and $Y'$ such that etc.

Comment: @Did great, thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Did already gave a clear explanation to your doubt. For further clarification, to see that $d_{TV}(X,Y)=0 $ does not imply $P(X=Y)=1$ and rather means $X\stackrel{d}{=}Y$, consider two i.i.d random variables $X,Y\sim Bern(p)$, then, $d_{TV}(X,Y)=0$, but $P(X=Y)=p^2+(1-p)^2\ne 1$